# Summarize li data to the divider bubble

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a possible way to take data-amount form same category Li elements and put em as a sum to the divider with the same category, to the bubble. I tried with SQLite, got stacked on double execute. I hope there is a way to solve this. Need fresh eyes.

```
<ul data-role="listview">
  <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li-divider" data-category="">
     Category Not Set
     <span class="ui-li-count"></span>
  </li>
  <li data-row-id="1" data-amount="300" id="1" data-icon="info" data-category="">
     <a href="" data-view-id="1" class="viewCost ui-btn">
        <h2>Header 1</h2>
     </a>
  </li>
  <li data-row-id="2" data-amount="500" id="2" data-icon="info" data-category="">
     <a href="" data-view-id="2" class="viewCost ui-btn">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you have one category and two `li` elements. please clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **[each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)** function to iterate through all ui-li-dividers in your list. Then for each divider, you can use **[nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/)** to get sibling listitems until you reach the next divider. Once you have this list, get the data-amount attribute, parse it to integer and add them up. Finally set the count bubble text to the total:

```
$("#mylist .ui-li-divider").each(function(idx){
    var $bubble = $(this).find(".ui-li-count"); //the count bubble
    var total = 0;

    var $lis = $(this).nextUntil('.ui-li-divider'); //get listitems until next divider
    //iterate listitems, get the amount of each, add to total
    $lis.each(function(){
        var amount = parseInt($(this).jqmData('amount'));
        total += amount;
    });
    //write total to bubble
    $bubble.text(total);

});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/wwg7onfo/)**